# HorizontalScrollView in ListView items

Tags: android

I'm using a LinearLayout which contains an ImageView and a HorizontalScrollView as ListView items.

The problem is OnItemClickListener of the ListView doesn't work. After adding `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` on LinearLayout it works when ImageView is clicked but it doesn't work when HorizontalScrollView is clicked.

`android:focusable="false"` and `android:focusableInTouchMode="false"` doesn't work too.

I want regular clicks on HorizontalScrollView also fires OnItemClickListener of ListView.

I'm testing on android 4.2.2

Comment: Try adding android:focusable="false" attribute for the horizontal scroll view.

Comment: @nikvs doesn't work. also tried focusableInTouchMode="false"

Comment: Try to override interceptTouchListener... It will resolve your problem

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and did not find any better solution than just to assign `View.onClickListener` to descendant of `HorizontalScrollView`. In my case I needed to know the position value from `ArrayAdapter` belonging to the clicked `listview` item, which I passed to the view during the `getView` execution as a view tag.

```
RelativeLayout -> HorizontalScrollView -> Relative Layout @+id/clickit ...

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    layoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(resourceID, parent, false);

    MyType mt = getItem(position);

    RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) rowView.findViewById(R.id.clickit);
    rl.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            m_menuEventsListener.onActionsMenuClick(getItem((Integer) view.getTag()));
        }
    });
    rl.setTag(position);
}
```

Note that the same `m_menuEventsListener.onActionsMenuClick` is called from the onItemClickListener attached to the listview. `m_menuEventsListener` is my own listener implemented in the Activity.